# Deegree: how to cope with GML with an Arc: "Cannot determine control points for ring, contains non-linear segments"?

Tags: gml, deegree

How can I read with 'deegree' a GML3.2 with an arc?

The simplified data contains an arc:

```
<gml:Polygon>
  <gml:exterior>
    <gml:Ring>
      <gml:curveMember>
        <gml:Curve>
          <gml:segments>
            <gml:LineStringSegment>
              <gml:posList>44.605 773.516 40.806 775.320</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineStringSegment>
            <gml:LineStringSegment>
              <gml:posList>40.806 775.320 38.522 759.491</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineStringSegment>
            <gml:LineStringSegment>
              <gml:posList>38.522 759.491 45.178 773.702</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineStringSegment>
            <gml:Arc>
              <gml:posList>45.178 773.702 44.930 773.491 44.605 773.516</gml:posList>
            </gml:Arc>
          </gml:segments>
        </gml:Curve>
      </gml:curveMember>
    </gml:Ring>
  </gml:exterior>
</gml:Polygon>
```

When performing this method

```
GMLObject gmlObject = null;
XMLStreamReader r = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(gml));
GMLStreamReader gmlStreamReader = GMLInputFactory.createGMLStreamReader(gmlVersion, r);
gmlObject = gmlStreamReader.read(); // --> error 1
gmlObject.toString(); // --> error 2
```

I get these errors:

> 1. Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception. Cannot evaluate
>    org.deegree.geometry.standard.primitive.DefaultPolygon.toString()
> 2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine control points for ring, contains non-linear segments.

How to cope with this issue?

Comment: I suggest to fix the data. The upper level element is <gml:Polygon> that can contain only straight segments and therefore gml:Arc gives an error. A PolygonPatch http://www.datypic.com/sc/niem21/e-gml32_PolygonPatch.html can contain curved elements.

Comment: In the mean time I see that other systems with samen XSD can work the arcs within polygons. Please see http://www.datypic.com/sc/niem21/e-gml32_Polygon.html.

Comment: You are probably right. GDAL finds this geometry from your GML: `CURVEPOLYGON (COMPOUNDCURVE ((44.605 773.516,40.806 775.32),(40.806 775.32,38.522 759.491),(38.522 759.491,45.178 773.702),CIRCULARSTRING (45.178 773.702,44.93 773.491,44.605 773.516)))`. Write mail to deegree users mailing list and ask https://sourceforge.net/p/deegree/mailman/deegree-users/.

Comment: Thank you. I have made this issue: https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/issues/1574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

[The GML is not valid] -> I suppose that deegree thinks that the GML is not valid, because the upper level element is `<gml:Polygon>`,  and by some definitions polygons can contain only straight segments. Maybe therefore `<gml:Arc>` that appears deeper in the data gives an error.

Arc and other curved element are allowed in a PolygonPatch https://datypic.com/sc/niem21/e-gml32_PolygonPatch.html.

Comment: Is the above really true? Other systems can work with arcs within a polygon. This is what I can find: http://www.datypic.com/sc/niem21/e-gml32_Polygon.html. You can click on polygon > exterior > ring > curveMember > curve > segments > arc.

Comment: I edited the answer to ponder if that's how the deegree software is analyzing the GML.